# JavaScript submit does not work in Chrome/Safari, but works fine in Firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I did a research and i didn't find solution. I am trying to submit a form using javascript method submit(). The code below shows what i am trying to do. This code works fine in firefox and IE, but in chrome and safari, the form does not submit. 
Can someone gives me an idea, what i am doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance !

```
<body>

    <form method="post" id="simpleForm">
        <select name="selectMenu" >
            <option id="1" value="1" onclick="ssform();">1</option>
            <option id="2" value="2" onclick="ssform();">2</option>
            <option id="3" value="3" onclick="ssform();">3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <script>
        function ssform() {
            document.getElementById("simpleForm").submit();
        }
    </script>

    <?php
        var_dump($_POST['selectMenu']);
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event handlers attached to options does not work on every browser. Use the change event on the select.

```
<select name="selectMenu" onchange="ssform();">
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. But this do not solve my problem. When i add the ssform() function to the select, it submits the form immidiatelly when you click on it. I mean there is no time to select option.

Comment: Did you use change?

Comment: Sorry I did not undestand your question. What do you mean by use change ? 
I put : onclick="ssform();" into the select element and test it out. Could you help me with better explanation ? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Look at the code I have. It is change, not click.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works fine now.